# Trying to display random javascript images in separate DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have working `javascript` code that produces multiple random images in to one `div`.
I have tried a few attempts to display each random image in a separate `div` but with no luck. I got "close" but no success.
Here is working code:

```html
<head>
<style>
  .onetwothreefour {
width: 25%;
display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

<script>
function displayNow() {
  var images = ["00.png","01.png","02.png","03.png","04.png","05.png","06.png"];
  var selectedIndices = []
  while (selectedIndices.length < 4) {
    var index = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]
    if (selectedIndices.indexOf(index) == -1) {
      selectedIndices.push(index)
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < selectedIndices.length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "imagesfolder/" + selectedIndices[i]
    img.className = "onetwothreefour"
    var src = document.getElementById("images");
    src.appendChild(img);
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="displayNow();">

  <div id="images"><!-- Images --></div>
  <!-- the above works fine but I would like the result below -->

  <div class="container"><div class="row">    
  <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
  <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
  <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
  <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
  </div></div>

</body>
```

Note: I have `jquery` and `bootstrap` loaded.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explaination** : The `while` loop runs for four times. A random index is generated, and the element is removed from `images` array, and pushed into `selectedIndices` array. By this way, no iteration will be wasted, as each time, a unique image will be generated. I have used `forEach` loop, which iterates over all the elements of `selectedIndices` array.

**NOTE** : The comment inside the `forEach` loop is a one line way to do so. However, using `innerHTML` is not appreciated sometimes.

```js
function displayNow() {
  var images = ["00.png", "01.png", "02.png", "03.png", "04.png", "05.png", "06.png"];
  var selectedIndices = [];
  var src = document.getElementById("images");

  while (selectedIndices.length < 4) {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    let img = images.splice(index, 1)[0];
    selectedIndices.push(img)
  }

  selectedIndices.forEach((el) => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = "imagesfolder/" + el;
    img.alt = el;
    img.className = "onetwothreefour";
    let imgCont = document.createElement("div");
    imgCont.append(img);
    src.append(imgCont);

    // src.innerHTML += "<div><img class='onetwothreefour' src='imagesfolder/" + el + "' alt='" + el + "'></div>";
  });
}
```

```css
.onetwothreefour {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="displayNow();">
  <div id="images"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
      <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
      <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
      <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have not tried this version yet. I just finished with answer #1. I will need to do similar with your code and add the class="col" to the generated divs. I presume just after this code:  let imgCont = document.createElement("div");

Comment: Yeah, class will be added after the declaration of `imgCont` element.

Comment: Well your "more efficient" code works too. And there is a perceived slightly better pop to the images as a bonus to my question. Thank you too. I will use this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using `createElement()` to build the `img` elements - you can use the same method to create a new `div`, add the child `img` to it, then append that to the DOM. Try this:

```js
function displayNow() {
  var src = document.getElementById("images");
  var images = ["00.png", "01.png", "02.png", "03.png", "04.png", "05.png", "06.png"];
  var selectedIndices = []
  
  while (selectedIndices.length < 4) {
    var index = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]
    if (selectedIndices.indexOf(index) == -1) {
      selectedIndices.push(index)
    }
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < selectedIndices.length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "imagesfolder/" + selectedIndices[i]
    img.className = "onetwothreefour";
    img.title = selectedIndices[i]; // just for this demo
    
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.append(img);
    src.append(div);
  }
}
```

```css
.onetwothreefour {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="displayNow();">
  <div id="images">
    <!-- Images -->
  </div>

  <!-- the above works fine but I would like the result below -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
      <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
      <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
      <div id="" class=""><img src="" id="" class=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I added div.className = "col"; beneath the createElement so the generated divs had that col class for bootstrap. I also added the ID to the div row: div class="row" id="images".